# can't install memcache php module

Tags: php, memcached, xampp

i'm trying to install memcache module from http://pecl.php.net/package/memcache. Im using xampp in ubuntu (lampp) with php 5.3.  After download the extension, I run phpize, make and make install, then I add extension=memcache.so in my php.ini but when I restart xampp the following message appears:

> Warning: PHP Startup: memcache: Unable
>   to initialize module Module compiled
>   with module API=20060613 PHP
>   compiled with module API=20090626
>   These options need to match  in
>   Unknown on line 0

Anyone have any ideia on what happening?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

5.3 Is known to give problems. Go back to 5.2.3.

Does this http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=42187 answer your question?